# Chrome extension with tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension, autofill

I have been spending my last three days on trying to get this work, so please don't reply with a link to the chrome API or something like that.

I'm developing a Chrome extension that comunicates with a mySql database, to get the favorite websites of a user, and the login/password for each of this websites (let's say facebook fbuser fbpass, google gguser ggpass...)

So the goal of the extension is to open a new tab for each website, and do the login.

I've stablished the communication with the database, and I can succesfully open new tabs with the websites, but I'm stacked on inserting the username and the password on each website. My problem is that I cannot use document.getElementsById('input')... because it returns me the elements on my popup, not on the webpage.

So I've read about chrome.tabs.executeScript(), and I'm trying to use it (it seems that is what I need to use to access the DOM of the webpage).

So I'm using something like:

```
chrome.tabs.create({"url": web[i],"selected":false},function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"write.js"}, function(){
        });
        });
```

And the "write.js" must do the autofill.

So here starts my problems:

I have an "alert("I'm in");" message inside write.js, and it is never shown (so the rest of the function is never called). (I found this function "write.js" in internet).

And here I'll post parts of my popup html, manifest and the js, maybe I have to change something there because I've tried what I've seen in most examples and is not working for me.

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyExtension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My chrome extension",
  "icons":{
      "128":"icon_128.png"
  },
  "browser_action":   {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "popup": "consulta_empleados.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

consulta_empleados.html (the popup):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Consulta Registro con AJAX</title>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" >
  <label>
  <div align="center">Email<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  </label>
  <p align="center">
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="open" id="open" value="Log In" onClick="runScript()">
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
<div id="prova"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

file ajax.js:

```
function runScript(){
      ...
      //here I fill a vector with the usernames, the websites and the passwords from the data coming from my database. var num is the number of websites
      ...
  var i=0;
  while(i<num){
    chrome.tabs.create({"url": web[i],"selected":false},function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "write.js"}, function(){

        });
        });
    i++;
  }

}

write.js:
function write() {
     ...
      alert("I'm in");
     ...      
} 
write();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using content script instead of `executeScript`? It is worth trying. If it won't help, let me know - I'll try to debug your extension.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO instead of "selected":false you need "active":false

you can also thest this by adding another alert before chrome.tabs.executeScript, to see if the callback of chrome.tabs.create is being called

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same result. I also have tried putting another alert in the callback function of the chrome.tabs.create , and it is never shown.

Comment: so you're not even creating the tab? Or the tab is created, but the callback not called?

Comment: Yes the tab is created, but the callback not called.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at your devtools' console, there must be some error message.
To use contentscript, you need `tabs` permission

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://www.google.com/*"
  ],
  ...
}
```